# SQL getting sum of particular column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a csv file where i am uploading it to postgres using node js . The csv file looks like below

```
Employee ID UID Name    Base Pay    Payout
987         123 Test    71777       200
987         123 Test    71788       250
```

I want to display both the rows as the base pay is different but i need sum of payout in both the rows like below

```
Employee ID UID  Name   Base Pay    Payout
987         123  Test   71777       450
987         123  Test   71788       450
```

Is this possible by single sql. I am trying the below query but it is displaying only single row

```
SELECT employee_id,uid, employee_name, SUM(CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(payout, ''), '0') AS decimal)) AS amount
FROM employee_table where employee_id = '987'
GROUP BY employee_id, uid, employee_name
```

I am trying the below query but it is displaying only single row

```
SELECT employee_id,uid, employee_name, SUM(CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(payout, ''), '0') AS decimal)) AS amount
FROM employee_table where employee_id = '987'
GROUP BY employee_id, uid, employee_name
```

Comment: Provide a table definition, and show data as text, not as image, please. Always disclose your Postgres version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an `OVER` clause in your sum. As long as you want to select data for one employee_id only, this will be enough:

```
SELECT 
  employee_id, uid, employee_name, base_pay, 
  SUM(payout) OVER() AS payout
FROM employee_table
WHERE employee_id = 987;
```

If you want to select more or all employees, then extend above query by `PARTITION BY employee_id`:

```
SELECT 
  employee_id, uid, employee_name, base_pay, 
  SUM(payout) OVER(PARTITION BY employee_id) AS payout
FROM employee_table;
-- WHERE employee_id IN (987,988...), if required
```

Thus, the sum will be build per employee_id rather than over all employees.

Try out with some sample data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/e6dJ9CNY)

I recommend to read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) about `window functions`.